# The definition of torsion functor

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

I'm learning Algebraic Topology by Massey . In chapter $6$ Homology with Arbitrary Coefficient group , he assumes knowledge of The Tor functor . So I tried to find the definition of Tor on Internet , specifically in Gradute texts - Rotman .

For each abelian group $A$ , choose an exact sequence $0 \to R \to F \to A \to 0$ with $F$ is free abelian . For any abelian group $B$ , define

$$\text{Tor}(A,B) = ker( (R \to F) \otimes 1_{B} )$$

He also wrote : " If we delete $A$ then $C_{*} = 0 \to R \to F \to 0$ is a chain complex as is $C_{*} \otimes B  = 0 \to R \otimes B \to F \otimes B \to 0$ ( just attach a sequence of zeros ) . Hence $\text{Tor}(A,B) = H_{1}(C_{*} \otimes B)$ "

I don't understand why has this definition ( I knew there is another definition with show all relations and generators ) and the last paragraph ?

Finally for a short exact sequence of abelian groups I want to prove the following  ( here I understand Tor in another way which is deffirent from above )

$$0 \to A' \to A \to A'' \to 0$$

We also have the exact sequence :

$$0 \to \text{Tor}(A',B) \to \text{Tor}(A,B) \to \text{Tor}(A'',B) \to A' \otimes B \to A \otimes B \to A'' \otimes B \to 0$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear to which alternative definition of $\operatorname{Tor}$ you refer to.

Assuming you are familiar with some properties of tensor products, here's a more or less self-contained proof, which may be extracted from any textbook on homological algebra.

- The definition you give is correct: to calculate $\operatorname{Tor} (A,B)$, one should pick a short exact sequence
  $$\tag{1} 0 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to A \to 0$$
  where $F_0$ is a free abelian group (and hence $F_1$ is free as well, being a subgroup of $F_0$). Then you should tensor it with $B$, and the result is
  $$0\to \operatorname{Tor} (A,B) \to F_1\otimes B \to F_0\otimes B\to A\otimes B\to 0$$
  In other words, we declare $\operatorname{Tor} (A,B)$ to be the kernel of $F_1\to F_0$ tensored with $B$. (Note that $F_0\otimes B\to A\otimes B$ will still be an epimorphism. It is the monomorphism $F_1 \to F_0$ which after tensoring with $B$ may have a nonrivial kernel.)

(*One should also justify why different choices of (1) lead to the same $\operatorname{Tor} (A,B)$. This is true, but let me omit this verification, as this post is already long enough.*)

- Note that if you have a short exact sequence of *free* abelian groups
  $$0 \to F' \to F \to F'' \to 0$$
  then tensoring with $B$ gives you again a short exact sequence
  $$0 \to F'\otimes B \to F\otimes B \to F''\otimes B \to 0$$
  This agrees with our definition according to which $\operatorname{Tor} (A,B) = 0$ if $A$ is free.
- If you erase $A$ from the short exact sequence (1), you obtain a chain complex
  $$F_\bullet\colon\quad 0 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to 0$$
  where $F_1$ sits in degree $1$ and $F_0$ sits in degree $0$. If you tensor this chain complex with $B$, you get a chain complex
  $$F_\bullet\otimes B\colon\quad 0 \to F_1\otimes B \to F_0\otimes B \to 0$$
  Its homology in degree $0$ is given by
  $$H_0 (F_\bullet\otimes B) = \frac{\ker (F_0\otimes B \to 0)}{\operatorname{im} (F_1\otimes B \to F_0\otimes B)} = \operatorname{coker} (F_1\otimes B \to F_0\otimes B) \cong A\otimes B,$$
  and its homology in degree $1$ is given by
  $$H_1 (F_\bullet\otimes B) = \frac{\ker (F_1\otimes B \to F_0\otimes B)}{\operatorname{im} (0 \to F_1\otimes B)} = \ker (F_1\otimes B \to F_0\otimes B),$$
  which is $\operatorname{Tor} (A,B)$ by our definition.
- The point of the above is the following. If you have a short exact sequence of abelian groups
  $$\tag{2} 0 \to A' \to A \to A'' \to 0$$
  then to calculate $\operatorname{Tor} (A',B)$, $\operatorname{Tor} (A,B)$, $\operatorname{Tor} (A'',B)$, you should pick short exact sequences
  $$\tag{3} 0 \to F_1' \to F_0' \to A' \to 0$$
  $$\tag{4} 0 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to A \to 0$$
  $$\tag{5} 0 \to F_1'' \to F_0'' \to A'' \to 0$$
  In fact you may do even better: first pick (3) and (5):

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@.0    @.@.  0\\
@.@VVV  @. @VVV \\
@.F_1'    @.@.  F_1''\\
@.@VVV  @. @VVV \\
@.F_0'    @.@. F_0'' \\
@.@VVV  @. @VVV \\
0 @>>> A' @>>> A @>>> A'' @>>> 0 \\
@.@VVV  @. @VVV \\
@.0    @.@.  0
\end{CD}$$
and then it is possible to build a short exact sequence (4) that gives a commutative diagram with exact rows and columns

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@.0    @. 0 @.  0\\
@.@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> F_1' @>>> F_1 @>>> F_1'' @>>> 0 \\
@.@VVV  @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> F_0' @>>> F_0 @>>> F_0'' @>>> 0 \\
@.@VVV  @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> A' @>>> A @>>> A'' @>>> 0 \\
@.@VVV  @VVV @VVV \\
@.0   @. 0 @.  0
\end{CD}$$

(This is known as the "horseshoe lemma", and here's how to do that: you may take $F_0 = F_0'\oplus F_0''$. There is a homomorphism $F_0'\to A$, which is just the composition of arrows $F_0'\to A$ and $A'\to A$, and also a homomorphism $F_0''\to A$, which is a lifting of the homomorphism $F_0'' \to A$ along the epimorphism $A\to A''$. Such a lifting is possible since $F_0''$ is free. These two arrows give you an arrow $F_0'\oplus F_0'' \to A$. Now repeat the same to obtain $F_1 = F_1'\oplus F_1''$ together with an arrow $F_1\to F_0$.)

So starting from (4), we obtained a short exact sequence of chain complexes
$$\tag{6} 0 \to F_\bullet' \to F_\bullet \to F_\bullet'' \to 0$$
Now as these complexes consist of free abelian groups, after tensoring with $B$, we still get a short exact sequence of complexes
$$0 \to F_\bullet'\otimes B \to F_\bullet\otimes B \to F_\bullet''\otimes B \to 0$$
It remains to invoke the following **important theorem**:

> A short exact sequence of complexes
>   $$0 \to A_\bullet \to B_\bullet \to C_\bullet \to 0$$
>   induces a long exact sequence of homology groups
>   $$\cdots \to H_n (A_\bullet) \to H_n (B_\bullet) \to H_n (C_\bullet) \to H_{n-1} (A_\bullet) \to \cdots$$

In our case this long exact sequence reads

\begin{multline}
0 \to H_1 (F_\bullet'\otimes B) \to H_1 (F_\bullet\otimes B) \to H_1 (F_\bullet''\otimes B) \to\\
H_0 (F_\bullet'\otimes B) \to H_0 (F_\bullet\otimes B) \to H_0 (F_\bullet''\otimes B) \to 0
\end{multline}

($H_2 = 0$ in our case). This is precisely the exact sequence with $\operatorname{Tor}$s!

- There is no way you can go through an algebraic topology class without seeing the **important theorem** that I quote above. It is proved using the [snake lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma), but in our case everything is even easier. The short exact sequence of complexes (6) is nothing more than the following commutative diagram with exact rows

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>> F_1' @>>> F_1 @>>> F_1'' @>>> 0 \\
@.@VVV  @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> F_0' @>>> F_0 @>>> F_0'' @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

After tensoring this with $B$, we obtain a diagram (still with exact rows, because the involved groups are free)

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>> F_1'\otimes B @>>> F_1\otimes B @>>> F_1''\otimes B @>>> 0 \\
@.@VVV  @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> F_0'\otimes B @>>> F_0\otimes B @>>> F_0''\otimes B @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

Applying the snake lemma to this diagram, you get

\begin{multline}
0 \to \ker (F_1'\otimes B\to F_0'\otimes B) \to \ker (F_1\otimes B\to F_0\otimes B) \to \ker (F_1''\otimes B\to F_0''\otimes B) \to \\
\operatorname{coker} (F_1'\otimes B\to F_0'\otimes B) \to \operatorname{coker} (F_1\otimes B\to F_0\otimes B) \to \operatorname{coker} (F_1''\otimes B\to F_0''\otimes B) \to 0
\end{multline}

which is again the exact sequence we are looking for.

Comment: Oh , I knew these lemmas but didn't know their name .